# SIGSEGV memory access violation

Tags: c, memory, access-violation, segmentation-fault

I am writing a school project in C and apparently something in this code is causing it to crash with SIGSEGV memory access violation error even though it compiles without any problems.

```
int P, H, S, R;
char *end;

if (argc != 5){
    printf("Incorrect ammount of parameters.\n");
    exit(1);
}

errno = 0;
P=strtod(argv[2],&end);
H=strtod(argv[3],&end);
S=strtod(argv[4],&end);
R=strtod(argv[5],&end);

if (errno != 0){
    printf("Wrong input: %s\n",strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

//I know have only integers in P,H,S,R, that's why I can afford to do the following. Please don't judge me.
if ((H < 0) || (S < 0) || (R < 0) || (H > 5000) || ( S > 5000) || ( R > 5000)){
    printf("Incorrect waiting time H,S,R >= 0 && H,S,R < 5001\n");
    exit(1);
}

if ((P < 1) || ((P % 2)==1)){
    printf("Must be even number bigger than 0.");
    exit(1);
}
```

Any ideas?
EDIT: even if I put printf at the very beginning of the code i does not print anything, only memory access violation error which looks like this

```
Neoprávněný přístup do paměti (SIGSEGV) (core dumped [obraz paměti uložen])
```

Comment: OK, you are inexperienced, fine.  Google 'debugger' and find one that is applicable to your process.  Use  it to narrow down, or solve, your problem.

Comment: obviously not all of the code is shown, so we can only speculate... Why dont you debug it yourself and see at which line it is crashing? And BTW it is called a segmentation fault

Comment: note that you've a condition to ensure argc is 5, and you're accessing the argv[5] index (which will require a argc == 6).

Comment: @Cool_Coder: `SIGSEGV` refers to a "*Segmentation Violation*. Mind the "***V***".

Comment: @alk thanks for pointing. I need some sleep now maybe.

Comment: this is still a problem in NX siemens step214 importer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if (argc != 5)
…
R=strtod(argv[5],&end);
```

When `argc == 5`, `argv[5] == NULL`.  You crash when you convert a null pointer.  You should be using `strtod()` on `argv[1]` through `argv[4]`.  It is unusual to use `strtod()` to convert strings to integers; usually, you'd use `strtol()` or one of its relatives.

Answer (score 2):

It would be best if you could track down the exact line where the error is occurring.  You can do that in a debugger, or simply by putting `printf` statements all over the place and seeing what the last one that works is.

However, from a quick look, I think that the problem is here:

```
R=strtod(argv[5],&end);
```

SIGSEGV (segmentation fault) means that you attempted an invalid memory access.  A few lines up, you checked that `argc == 5`.  This means that the valid indices for `argv` are 0 through 4.  There is no `argv[5]`, and any attempt to read it results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Actually, `argv[argc]` is mandated to be a null pointer, isn't it?